# Codeigniter Pagination in Search Results

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I've already finished coding my search function in my website but it lacks pagination. So now, I tried to implement pagination to it, but there seems to be a problem. By using isset to my search query, I will not be able to load the page two of the pagination, since the query will always result to false. How can I properly implement the pagination in the search function?

Controller:

```
    function search_homeowner()
    {
         $this->load->model('model_accounts');
         $searchquery = $this->input->post('search');

         if(isset($searchquery) and !empty($searchquery))
         {
            $query =   $this->db->select('*')->from('accounts')->where('(role = 0 AND isActive = 1)',NULL,FALSE)->where('(CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR firstname LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR lastname LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR username LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR address LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" )',NULL,FALSE)->get();
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('admin_accounts/search_homeowner');
            $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
            $config['per_page'] =  15;
            $config_deact['num_links'] = 5;
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
            $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a>";
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
            $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['homeownerlinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

            $data['users'] = $this->model_accounts->search_homeowner($searchquery, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
            $data['main_content'] = 'view_adminaccounts';

            $this->load->view('includes/admin_accounts_template', $data);
         }
         else
        {
            redirect('admin_accounts/homeowner');
        }
     }
```

Model:

```
function search_admin($searchquery)
{
  $this->db->select('*')->from('accounts');
  $this->db->where('(role = 1 AND isActive = 1)',NULL,FALSE);
  $this->db->where('(CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR firstname LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR lastname LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR username LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" OR address LIKE "%'.$searchquery .'%" )',NULL,FALSE);
  $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to check if a page number is set and if so limit the query

Comment: Is it better to use GET than POST?

Comment: I would use the URL Helper in your situation, so you can get the page number by reading in the url segment like `$this->uri->segment(n);` ;)